# C++ output files

Tags: c++, input, io, output

I am trying to export the contents of a tree with recursion. I am not getting anything but the last element exported.

```
void inOrder(tree *root) {
    out.open("output.txt");
    if (root != NULL)
    {
        inOrder (root->left);
        out << root -> item << " \t";      //This doesn't work
        cout << root -> item << " \t";       //This works
        inOrder (root->right);
    }

    out.close();
    out.clear();
}
```

I'm not sure where I am going wrong when exporting here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move your

```
out.open("output.txt");
```

and

```
out.close();
out.clear();
```

outside your function, as during the recursion you end up re-opening the file (which will cause a stream error), then closing it. In fact, you don't even need the last two of them, the destructor of the `ofstream` will automatically close the file when the program terminates.

Comment: Doesn't seem to do anything. Should I call out.open(); out.close(); out.clear(); from main?

Comment: @skarchmit yes. You only need to open the file in `main()`, then pass the reference to the `ofstream` to your function.

Comment: I moved all of them out of the function, put them in main, and it worked.